# Docker Neo4j Container keeps stopping - how to debug?

Tags: neo4j, docker

We have a neo4j container and it keeps stopping.

There are 3 other containers (node servers) running on the box as well. It's on a dev box so it is low spec - only 588MB RAM- so I suspect that it keeps running out of memory.

But how do I verify why it keeps stopping?  Its only ever the neo container that stops. We launch it with:

```
$NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j console
```

I suspect its the neo4j process itself that is exiting, thus closing the container.
Any tips on debugging this?

Comment: Did you configure the JAVA heap?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the log files, which are by default in the `data/log` subdirectory of your neo4j installation directory.

Comment: Thanks, the logs in `data/log` just have...

`Jun 09, 2015 1:25:19 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'`

Comment: I also checked `/data/graph.db/messages.log` which has lots of `WARN` entries like this...

`2015-06-07 06:46:38.812+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 626ms [total block time: 41.373s]`

After a whole load of those, it then runs over the boot process again (after I bring it up).

But no errors as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you start it with

```
docker run --name <container_name> ... neo4j`
```

as [official man](https://neo4j.com/developer/docker/) propose, you can check errors with `docker logs <container_name>`

Also you can start it with additional volume

```
--volume=/path/to/logs:/logs
```

and check them